# call many classes in java - android studio

Tags: java, android, oop

I have many activities in (classes) so i want to call one of them from an other activity.
i name those classes (step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, ...)
that's my code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    for (int i = 0; i < stepsButtons.length; i++){
        if (stepsButtons[i].getId() == v.getId()) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this, step1.class));
}
```

I don't want to use like:

```
if (index == 0)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, step1.class));
else if (index == 1)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, step2.class));
...
```

i want to know if there is any way like:

```
String className = "step" + i;
startActivity(new Intent(this, className.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use introspection do achieve that, for example:

```
String className = "step" + i;
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
startActivity(new Intent(this, clazz));
```